# Does npx no longer do install-less run?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

From the [nodejs.dev site](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-npx-nodejs-package-runner):

> npx allows you to run that npm command without installing it first. If the command isn't found, npx will install it into a central cache:

They use this as an example:

```
npx cowsay "Hello"
```

But when I run that:

```
$ npx cowsay "Hello"

Need to install the following packages:
  cowsay
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

Huh? Is there some preference that I need to set now? I'm used to `npx` running things without installing them, like they say on nodejs.dev. I don't really want to install `cowsay` in my globals.

```
Node v14.17.5
NPM 7.21.0
OS:ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
```

Filed as an issue here: https://github.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/issues/4104

Edit: just tested this in NPM 6 and it works as expected. This might be a change in NPM post v6.

```
✗ npm --version
6.14.16

✗ npx cowsay "Hello"

npx: installed 41 in 7.509s
 _______
< Hello >
...
```

Comment: [ran across the exact same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235145/npx-on-windows-10-with-nvm-causes-need-to-install-following-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a change after NPM 6.

```
$ nvm install 18
Downloading and installing node v18.0.0...
...

$ nvm use 18  # this was a fresh install 
Now using node v18.0.0 (npm v8.6.0)


$ npx cowsay "Node 18"
Need to install the following packages:
  cowsay
Ok to proceed? (y) y
 _________
< Node 18 >
 ---------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

$ nvm use 14
Now using node v14.19.1 (npm v6.14.16)

$ npm uninstall --global cowsay # in case I already had it installed
up to date in 0.037s

$ npx cowsay "Node 14"  # NOTE: no confirmation 
npx: installed 41 in 5.271s
 _________
< Node 14 >
 ---------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Note: no confirmation for the install in Node 14.

If you want to use a package without confirming the install in Node 7+ you'll need to add the confirm flag. [See @Nitesh's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69006263/30946)

Answer (score 29):

You can do following if you are not willing to type 'yes' everytime you install.

```
npm_config_yes=true npx cowsay "hello"
```

See this https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2226

`npx` also has a `--yes` flag you can use to bypass the prompt:

```
npx --yes some-npm-package
```

This is undocumented if you run `npx --help`, but the documentation for this flag is hidden in the command's "description" on the [NPM website](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx#description).

There is also a `--no` flag available if you need to reject the prompt instead.

Comment: There is also a `--yes` flag you can use instead. The "moderators" apparently don't like that being posted as an answer, so here's a link instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70742969/1316229

Comment: @twiz I guess the mod decided it was too similar. I added your text to the answer.

Comment: `-y` is the same as `--yes`

Comment: Note that the `--yes` / `-y` flag is only available in NPM 7+. It is not available in 6.x, since NPM 6 does not prompt for confirmation, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/71961140/1438576. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx#compatibility-with-older-npx-versions