# npx on windows 10 with nvm causes need to install following packages

Tags: node.js, windows, nvm, npx

I've installed [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and nvm list shows

```
    17.2.0
  * 16.13.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    14.5.0
    10.21.0
    8.12.0
```

If I run `npx -v` I get `8.1.2` but if I run say `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` then I get

```
Need to install the following packages:
  create-next-app@latest
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

If I switch to 14.5.0 by saying `nvm use 14.5.0` and then run `npx -v` I get `6.14.0` & if I then run say `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` then I get the expected output of

```
npx: installed 1 in 1.772s
? What is your project named? » my-app
```

With nvm use 17.2.0, behaves similar to nvm use 16.13.1. and with 17.2.0, running `npx -v` outputs `8.1.4`

For nvm use 10.21.0 and 8.12.0, npx works as expected without asking me to download create-next-app globally as it does with node versions higher than 14.5.0.

One other thing with 14.5.0 and lower, if I do `npx --help` I get

```
Execute binaries from npm packages.

  npx [options] <command>[@version] [command-arg]...

  npx [options] [-p|--package <package>]... <command> [command-arg]...

  npx [options] -c '<command-string>'

  npx --shell-auto-fallback [shell]


Options:
  --package, -p          Package to be installed.                       [string]
  --cache                Location of the npm cache.                     [string]
  --always-spawn         Always spawn a child process to execute the command.
                                                                       [boolean]
  --no-install           Skip installation if a package is missing.    [boolean]
  --userconfig           Path to user npmrc.                            [string]
  --call, -c             Execute string as if inside `npm run-script`.  [string]
  --shell, -s            Shell to execute the command with, if any.
                                                       [string] [default: false]
  --shell-auto-fallback  Generate shell code to use npx as the "command not
                         found" fallback.
                                   [string] [choices: "", "bash", "fish", "zsh"]
  --ignore-existing      Ignores existing binaries in $PATH, or in the local
                         project. This forces npx to do a temporary install and
                         use the latest version.                       [boolean]
  --quiet, -q            Suppress output from npx itself. Subcommands will not
                         be affected.                                  [boolean]
  --npm                  npm binary to use for internal operations.
                                                              [string] [default:
  "C:\Users\Sangeet\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.5.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
                                                                               ]
  --node-arg, -n         Extra node argument when calling a node binary.[string]
  --version, -v          Show version number                           [boolean]
  --help, -h             Show help                                     [boolean]

For the full documentation, see the manual page for npx(1).
```

But with 16.13.1 and higher saying `npx --help` gives me

```
npm exec

Run a command from a local or remote npm package

Usage:
npm exec -- <pkg>[@<version>] [args...]
npm exec --package=<pkg>[@<version>] -- <cmd> [args...]
npm exec -c '<cmd> [args...]'
npm exec --package=foo -c '<cmd> [args...]'

Options:
[--package <pkg>[@<version>] [--package <pkg>[@<version>] ...]]
[-c|--call <call>]
[-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
[-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root]

alias: x

Run "npm help exec" for more info
```

I'm assuming npx comes "pre-installed" with npm so switching to any npm version higher that 5.2.0 should make npx available.

I can of course simply `nvm use 14.5.0` & go about my business but was very curious why npx is not behaving itself for 16.3.1 and 17.2.0. Unless I'm not doing some thing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is the new way npx behaves per [github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/nodejs.dev/issues/1849)

Seems [@jcollum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30946/jcollum) ran across the very same issue per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006097/does-npx-no-longer-do-install-less-run) stackoverflow question.

Comment: That GitHub issue link no longer exists.
THAT IS WHY YOU SHOULD ALWAYS **COPY THE RELVANT TEXT**!!!

Comment: @Mörre my bad, next time I'll make sure to copy the relevant text, I understand your angst though, this issue infuriated me when I first stumbled on it but if I remember correctly their response to that github issue was that they wouldn't be updating the message that is displayed and did not have the resources to update the documentation either, so we are stuck with the way things are for now.