# Automatically accept installing NPX package

Tags: shell, npm, npx

When running an NPM package with `npx` for the first time, it will display a prompt asking if you want to download the package.

For example, if you ran the command `npx some-npm-package`, you would receive the following prompt:

```
Need to install the following packages:
  some-npm-package
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

This is a problem if `npx` is being executed programmatically and you are unable to type input manually.

How can I automatically accept this prompt?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`npx` has a `--yes` flag you can use to bypass the prompt:

```
npx --yes some-npm-package
```

This is undocumented if you run `npx --help`, but the documentation for this flag is hidden in the command's "description" on the [NPM website](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx#description).

There is also a `--no` flag available if you need to reject the prompt instead.